# brew doctor warnings - delete library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew

I just installed Homebrew...I ran "brew doctor" and need help figuring the warnings.

Where is the libhelium_mac from? I recently downloaded the Mac OS X package on http://railsinstaller.org/en. I'm on Maverick.

I need step-by-step, command line-level help. Thank you!

> Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
>
> If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>
> building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected static libraries:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libhelium_mac.a
> ```
>
> Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
>
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
>
> `./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
>
> this other pkg-config.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libhelium_mac.a
```

It deleted the file, followed by me running:

```
sudo brew doctor
```

The system came back with:

```
Your system is ready to brew
```